# QgsNetworkReplyContent.content() empty after HTTP error

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt, flask

I have a custom Flask backend and a QGIS plugin as client. I make a request with the `QgsNetworkAccessmanager` with `blockingPost()` to an endpoint which returns a JSON response on either HTTP status.

That works fine for HTTP 200, but when an API error occurs, the `content()` of the `QgsNetworkReplyContent` is just empty (`b''`). I'm fairly sure I'm missing smth on the Flask side, because in other plugins requesting other (non-Flask) APIs I can correctly see the `content` error message.. I tried diving into the source code to see what the Flask response is missing, but it's quite hard since the whole network module mixes Qt and Qgs components quite heavily.

EDIT: This is the (quite standard) error handler in Flask:

```py
from werkzeug.exceptions import BadRequest

@api.errorhandler(BadRequest)
def handle_user_bad_post_error(e: BadRequest):
    return {'error': e.description}, 400
```

EDIT2: forgot to say that all other requesting methods I tried (curl, Postman) did response with the correct error message

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to catch the status of the HTTP code answer e.g different from 200, you can't get the error message from method `errorString` and/or `error` from your `QgsNetworkReplyContent` object like illustrated below ?

I would try to change the URL from 2nd example with your own to see content of `response.error()` and `response.errorString()`

**Working URL, HTTP 200**

```py
workingUrl = QUrl('http://example.com')

request = QNetworkRequest(workingUrl)
networkAccessManager = QgsNetworkAccessManager()
response = networkAccessManager.blockingGet(request)
status_code = response.attribute(QNetworkRequest.HttpStatusCodeAttribute)
if status_code == 200:
    print(response.content())
else:
    print(response.error())
    print(response.errorString())
```

**"Unworking URL" e.g HTTP different than 200**

```py
unworkingUrl = QUrl('https://gis.stackexchange.com/error')

request = QNetworkRequest(unworkingUrl)
networkAccessManager = QgsNetworkAccessManager()
response = networkAccessManager.blockingGet(request)
status_code = response.attribute(QNetworkRequest.HttpStatusCodeAttribute)
if status_code == 200:
    print(response.content())
else:
    print(response.error())
    print(response.errorString())
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, that's what I'm already doing, but that's not very satisfying unfortunately: the `errroString` is a generic error message Qt inserts for a specific error code. The `content` usually contains the server's custom message. But somehow not in Flask's case. I'll find a custom (public) Flask server to reproduce, give me a sec

Comment: Hm, my comment about other APIs handling the error response properly is also not valid.. I was 100% sure I got the error message for valhalla servers via `content` but can't reproduce now, e.g. `https://api.mapbox.com/valhalla/v1` also gives an empty `content()` on error. Then it's a bug if there's no way to access the server's response.. I'll file a ticket.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/42442

Comment: Confirmed it's a QGIS level not Qt e.g working with `QNetworkAccessManager` and `QNetworkReply` https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/85b65534beca578b8eab3826e50f0637 (adapted from https://zetcode.com/pyqt/qnetworkaccessmanager/)

Comment: Ah thanks for the insight @ThomasG77